Stream response using SSE or similar in Ktor for the Groq API (like OpenAI)
I am trying to stream data in real-time using Server-Sent Events (SSE) with Ktor for a Groq API (similar to OpenAI). However, the response seems to wait for the full data before processing, which is not the behavior I expect. I need the data to be streamed as soon as it is available, but it's waiting for the full response.

class ApiClient(
    private val apiKey: String,
    private val baseUrl: String = "https://api.groq.com/openai"
) {
    private val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json {
                encodeDefaults = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                explicitNulls = false
            })
        }
        install(SSE)
    }

    suspend fun chatCompletionCreateWithStream(
        model: String,
        messages: List<Message>,
        stream: Boolean = true,
        tool_choice: String = "auto",
        tools: List<Tool>? = null,
        coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Default
    ): Flow<Result<ChatCompletion>> {
        val requestPayload = ChatRequest(
            model = model,
            messages = messages,
            stream = stream,
            tool_choice = tool_choice,
            tools = tools
        )

        return flow {
            val response = client.post("$baseUrl/v1/chat/completions") {
                contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                headers {
                    append("Accept", "text/event-stream")
                    append("Authorization", "Bearer $apiKey")
                }
                setBody(requestPayload)
            }

            response.bodyAsChannel().apply {
                while (!isClosedForRead) {
                    val line = readUTF8Line(Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        ?.removePrefix("data: ")
                        ?.takeIf { it.startsWith("{") }
                        ?: continue

                    try {
                        val chunk = Json.decodeFromString<ChatCompletion>(line)
                        emit(Result.success(chunk))  // Emitting as the data comes in
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        emit(Result.failure<ChatCompletion>(e))
                    }
                }
            }
        }.flowOn(coroutineContext)
         .catch { e ->
             emit(Result.failure<ChatCompletion>(e))
         }
    }
}

Problem:
I want the data to be streamed in real-time as it is received (i.e., each chunk should be emitted as it arrives, without waiting for the entire response) but the code waits for the full response to be received and only then begins processing and emitting the chunks, which isn’t the intended behavior.
I am using SSE with the header Accept: text/event-stream to simulate streaming. However, the response isn't streamed properly in real-time, and the data is being emitted only after the full response is received.

So my question is: How can I ensure that data is processed and emitted in real-time, as soon as each chunk arrives, instead of waiting for the entire response?


Using bodyAsChannel() to read the response as a stream.
Using readUTF8Line() to process each line and emitting chunks via Kotlin Flow.
Setting the Accept: text/event-stream header for streaming.


I found the solution by myself here is my new code:
suspend fun chatCompletionCreateWithStream(
        model: String,
        messages: List<Message>,
        stream: Boolean = true,
        tool_choice: String = "auto",
        tools: List<Tool>? = null
    ): Flow<Result<ChatCompletion>> = flow {
        client.sse(
            urlString = "$baseUrl/v1/chat/completions",
            request = {
                method = HttpMethod.Post
                headers {
                    append("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    append("Accept", "text/event-stream")
                    append("Authorization", "Bearer $apiKey")
                }
                setBody(
                    ChatRequest(
                        model = model,
                        messages = messages,
                        stream = stream,
                        tool_choice = tool_choice,
                        tools = tools
                    )
                )
            }
        ) {
            incoming.collect { event ->
                try {
                    if (event.data == "[DONE]") {
                        return@collect
                    }
                    val chatCompletion = Json.decodeFromString(ChatCompletion.serializer(), event.data.toString())
                    emit(Result.success(chatCompletion))
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    emit(Result.failure(e))
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    emit(Result.failure(e))
                }
            }
        }
    }.catch { e ->
        // Catch any exceptions from the flow itself
        emit(Result.failure(e))
    }

